# Recasting const function

Tags: c++

I'm using a library (libtcod) that has an A* pathfinding algorithm. My class inherits the callback base class, and I implement the required callback function. Here is my generic example:

```
class MyClass : public ITCODPathCallback
{
...
public: // The callback function
   float getWalkCost(int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo, void *userData ) const 
   {
      return this->doSomeMath();
   };
   float doSomeMath() { // non-const stuff }
};
```

I found a number of examples using const_cast and static_cast, but they seemed to be going the other way, making a non-const function be able to return a const function result. How can I do it in this example?

getWalkCost() is defined by my library that I cannot change, but I want to be able to do non-const things in it.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You realize you're violating the contract of getWalkCost, which promises it doesn't modify anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution depends on why you want to do non-const stuff.  For example, if you have a cache of results that you want to use to improve performance, then you can make the cache be mutable, since that preserves the logical constness:

```
class MyClass : public ITCODPathCallback
{
...
public: // The callback function
   float getWalkCost(int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo, void *userData ) const 
   {
      return this->doSomeMath();
   };
   float doSomeMath() const { // ok to modify cache here }
   mutable std::map<int,int> cache;
};
```

Or perhaps you want to record some statistics about how many times the getWalkCost was called and what the maximum x value was, then passing a reference to the statistics may be best:

```
class MyClass : public ITCODPathCallback
{
...
public: 
   struct WalkStatistics {
     int number_of_calls;
     int max_x_value;

     WalkStatistics() : number_of_calls(0), max_x_value(0) { }
   };

   MyClass(WalkStatistics &walk_statistics)
     : walk_statistics(walk_statistics)
   {
   }

   // The callback function
   float getWalkCost(int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo, void *userData ) const 
   {
      return this->doSomeMath();
   };
   float doSomeMath() const { // ok to modify walk_statistics members here }
   WalkStatistics &walk_statistics;
};
```

Comment: You should also think about thread-safety when modifying an object via a `const` function. Even if you only think about it long enough to realize that you don't need to do anything about it because the object will only be used by a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it this way:

```
  return const_cast<MyClass*>(this)->doSomeMath();
```

Of course this won't be considered good design by most people, but hey.  If you prefer you can instead make doSomeMath() const, and mark the data members it modifies as `mutable`.